# Android - Why calling this function directly instead of onClick causes a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sinch

I am trying to integrate the [Sinch Android SDK](https://github.com/sinch/android-video-calling) in my project and I wanted to remove the Login button, i.e. such that the Activity switches to the next activity without the user having to click the Login button. For this, I removed the code for `setOnClickListener` for the `mLoginButton` and instead, directly called the `loginClicked()` function, which was previously being called from the `onClick()` method.
But this causes `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.yankee.cw.SinchService$SinchServiceInterface.isStarted()' on a null object reference`.
These are the only changes I made to the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        mLoginName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginName);

        mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        mLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
//        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                loginClicked();
//            }
//        });
        loginClicked();
    }
```

And earlier it was like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        mLoginName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginName);

        mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        mLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginClicked();
            }
        });
    }
```

Why doesn't this work and gives the `NullPointerException` instead ?

Edit: [LoginActivity.java](https://github.com/sinch/android-video-calling/blob/master/src/com/sinch/android/rtc/sample/video/LoginActivity.java)

Comment: provide loginClicked() method

Comment: It is already provided, the rest of the code is same as before. Sorry I didn't link it. I have added  the link now.

Comment: @Yankee please provide the loginClicked() method for the understanding the problem.

Comment: @LoveAndroid I've added the link in the edit.

Comment: Problem is in base activity. Make sure you have same base activity as provided in the sample. Also make you sure you provide username. I think it won't work without user name

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir , Yes, everything else is the same. I have also provided the usernames.

Comment: ok let me try that on my end then i will let you know

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir Thanks, I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: If you dont want a login I would not load a activity and close it, you should rather move the implementation to i.e on app started and use what ever username you have stored. As Ishan pointed out it works, but the implementation gets very hacky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getSinchServiceInterface()` method is returning null that is why you are getting null pointer exception.

Earlier `loginCliked()` method was getting called after button was enabled in `onServiceConnected` method.

try calling `loginClicked()`  method in `onServiceConnected()` method or use some delay.

Comment: Would you please mind explaining it to me briefly why `loginClicked()` needed to be placed in the `onServiceConnected()` ?

Comment: getSinchServiceInterface() is not getting initialized till onServiceConnected() method is called and that is why it is returning null.

Answer (score 2):

My solution :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       loginClicked();
    }
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check the formatting of your source code - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @Dekel well done, u saved my day.